# Why do so many Dunder Mifflin employees wear overcoats?

Tags: the-office

Michael wears one.  Dwight wears one.  Even Karen (different branch) wears one.  I believe I've seen episodes with Toby and David Wallace wearing them.

This is paper sales, not law, not a big business of any kind.

So why does it seem that overcoats (a la London Fog) are the most common type of jacket worn by Dunder Mifflin employees?

Answer (score 2):

> So why does it seem that overcoats (a la London Fog) are the most common type of jacket worn by Dunder Mifflin employees?

There are a multitude of episodes that take place during the winter season. With Dunder Mifflin being located up north / in the New England area (Pennsylvania, New York, Connecticut), IMO, it's no surprise that several employees wear an overcoat during those times.

Comment: This response does not address my question. I used to live in Boston. I owned many winter jackets. But I never owned an overcoat (a la London Fog).  It's the type I am asking about.

Comment: @JasonPSallinger If that's the case then the title of the question is fairly misleading.

Comment: @JasonPSallinger And, tbh, if that's the real nature of your question I doubt it'll actually get a valid answer. Just saying...